# How to store an Embind 'val' in a C++ class - error: call to deleted constructor

Tags: c++, emscripten, embind

I managed to use the [Embind val transliteration](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html#using-val-to-transliterate-javascript-to-c) to create a Web Audio API `AudioContext` and use it inside a function. But I do not understand how I can store it for later use in a C++ class instance field (`mContext`). When I compile the following code, I get

```
SC_WebAudio.cpp:62:20: error: call to deleted constructor of 'emscripten::val'
SC_WebAudioDriver::SC_WebAudioDriver(struct World* inWorld): SC_AudioDriver(inWorld) {}
                   ^
```

```cpp
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <emscripten/val.h>

using namespace emscripten;

class SC_WebAudioDriver : public SC_AudioDriver {
    val mContext;   // this doesn't work

protected:
    virtual bool DriverSetup(int* outNumSamplesPerCallback, double* outSampleRate);
    virtual bool DriverStart();
    virtual bool DriverStop();

public:
    SC_WebAudioDriver(struct World* inWorld);
    virtual ~SC_WebAudioDriver();
};

SC_AudioDriver* SC_NewAudioDriver(struct World* inWorld) { return new SC_WebAudioDriver(inWorld); }

SC_WebAudioDriver::SC_WebAudioDriver(struct World* inWorld): SC_AudioDriver(inWorld) {}

SC_WebAudioDriver::~SC_WebAudioDriver() {
}

bool SC_WebAudioDriver::DriverSetup(int* outNumSamples, double* outSampleRate) {
    scprintf("SC_WebAudio: DriverSetup.\n");

    // this uses the experimental emscripten Embind 'val' transliteration,
    // see https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/val.h.html
    val AudioContext = val::global("AudioContext");
    if (!AudioContext.as<bool>()) {
        AudioContext = val::global("webkitAudioContext");
        if (!AudioContext.as<bool>()) {
            scprintf("SC_WebAudioDriver: could not get hold of AudioContext\n");
            return false;
        }
    }

    val context = AudioContext.new_();
    mContext    = context;   // how to do this?
    double sr   = context["sampleRate"].as<double>();
    val proc    = context.call<val>("createScriptProcessor", 0, 0, 2);
    int bufSize = proc["bufferSize"].as<int>();

    *outNumSamples = bufSize;
    *outSampleRate = sr;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, the default constructor is `delete`d but you may be able to specify a suitable name when constructing it: `SC_WebAudioDriver::SC_WebAudioDriver(...): val("<name>") { ... }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`val` [has no default constructor](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/9c58ccb2cc55b5c9c2bd24ce962d4b1e924fb009/system/include/emscripten/val.h#L341-L352). Judging from the implementation, you might be able to initialize it with null or undefined as part of the initializer list:

```
class SC_WebAudioDriver : public SC_AudioDriver : mContext(val::undefined()) {...}
```

Alternatively, you can set a default value in the class definition:

```
class SC_WebAudioDriver : public SC_AudioDriver {
    val mContext = val::undefined();
```